# Return a value from a field of a table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I try to return a value of a field of a table, using the promises, but the result is displayed as below

```
router.get("/generateDemand", (req, res, next) => {
  const entreprise = req.user.entrepriseid;

  downloadFile(req, res, next, entreprise);
});
```

```
export const downloadFile = async (req, res, next, entreprise) => {
  const title1 = await Entreprise.findOne({
    attributes: ["entrepriseid", "titrefr"],
    where: { entrepriseid: entreprise }
  });
  console.log("title---------->", chalk.bgBlue(title1));
}
```

....

> Executing (default): SELECT "entrepriseid", "titrefr" FROM
>   "entreprise" AS "entreprise" WHERE "entreprise"."entrepriseid" =
>   'SDA'; title----------> [object SequelizeInstance:entreprise] GET
>   /attachment/generateDemand 200 71.459 ms - 1638

Comment: What is the issue? Where does `downloadFile()` return its result to the route? Where does the route respond to the client with the results from `downloadFile()`. Are you missing parts of your code or is your question that you do not know how to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

By calling the `findOne` method you return a single Sequelize model instance, so in order to get specified field of given instance (representation of table record), you should use the `instance.get` method like `chalk.bgBlue(title1.get('fieldName'))`